# Different behavior of jQuery.load function in local PC and server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used jQuery.load function to generate some dynamic page. I used POST method to send some data. The problem is, in my local PC (windows with Apache/php server) everything works fine, but when I upload it to my hosting server in internet (linux with Apache/php), it automatically add slashes to my string. Is jQuery have different behavior in different OS?

```
$("#fetch").click(function(){
    klist ="'a','b','c'";
    nlist ="'x','y','z'";
    $("#mydiv").load("tor.php", {n: nlist, k: klist},function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
});
```

Output of $_POST['n'] in tor.php is:

> Local server: "'x','y','z'" 
>   
> Internet Hosting server: "\'x\',\'y\',\'z\'"

Same for other variable.

Why it is happening and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than get into a whole thing about how you should install Linux on your local computer, the problem is that the remote server has the ini setting `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled.  Either disable this setting or just call `stripslashes` on all of the `$_POST` values.